# vb net format gives method not implemented error

Tags: vb.net, gridview, format

I have a VB net app, and use the format currency function in two modules. One works, the other causes a method not implemented error. I see a lot of stuff on the web about throwing exceptions or leaving the implementation empty. I understand neither. I also see info about form 2 inheriting form 1 and that's why it doesn't work on form 2. Only thing is....this one doesn't work on form 1 but does work on form 2. I'm stumped, I know is most likely basic stuff but I could sure use some guidance. Thanks!

I've tried this code:

```
sourceCarRow.Cells(11).Text = Format(Session("moveCharge"), "currency")
sourceCarRow.Cells(11).Text = Format(Session("moveCharge"), "$###,##0.00")
```

I have also tried adding the import statements from the working form to the non working form.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be calling that `Format` method in the first place. That exists basically for compatibility with upgraded VB6 code. You should be calling either the `ToString` method of the value you're formatting or the `String.Format` method or else using string interpolation. Either of the latter two can be handy when you have a boxed number, i.e. an `Object` reference rather than a numeric type, in which case `ToString` will not allow you to provide a format specifier without a cast first.

```vb
Dim num As Integer = 100
Dim obj As Object = 200

Dim str1 = num.ToString("C") 'Convert to currency using standard number of decimal places for current culture.
Dim str2 = num.ToString("C2") 'Convert to currency using specifically two decimal places.
Dim str3 = obj.ToString("C") 'Won't compile with Option Strict On and will throw an exception with Option Strict Off.
Dim str4 = obj.ToString("C2") 'Won't compile with Option Strict On and will throw an exception with Option Strict Off.
Dim str5 = String.Format("{0:C}", obj)
Dim str6 = String.Format("{0:C2}", obj)
Dim str7 = $"{obj:C}"
Dim str8 = $"{obj:C2}"
```

You should consult the documentation to learn what format specifiers are available for different purposes. This applies to numbers as well as date and times.